# How to interpolate hash element via reference returned by a method into a string?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I want to interpolate hash reference to string, but this method is not working.
How does one interpolate `$self->Test->{text}` ?

```
# $self->Test->{text} contains "test 123 ok"
print "Value is: $self->Test->{text} \n";   # but not working
```

output:

```
Test=HASH(0x2948498)->Test->{text}
```

Comment: you might find it useful to use Data::Dumper. It will pretty print object references for you...

Comment: So you are saying that `print "Value is: $self->Test->{text} \n";` actually prints the completely different string `Test=HASH(...)->MyModel->{init}`? Either your variables contain some `\r` characters, or you are incorrect about what your code/output is.

Comment: @TLP, I assume he's got an object blessed into a package called `Test`.

Comment: @friedo Yes. The question was edited, I assume he mixed up different print statements. It is still not correct output, as it does not contain `Value is: `. I find it strange that people submit approximative information when programming is so very detail oriented.

Comment: @TLP: yes, I've not finished writing the question that time, pardon me ^^

Answer (score 10):

Method calls won't get interpolated inside double quotes, so you end up with the stringified reference followed by `->Test->{text}`.

The simple way to do it is to take advantage of the fact that `print` takes a list of arguments:

```
print "Value is: ", $self->Test->{text}, "\n";
```

You could also use concatenation:

```
print "Value is: " . $self->Test->{text} . "\n";
```

You could also use the tried-and-true `printf`

```
printf "Value is %s\n", $self->Test->{text};
```

Or you can use this silly trick:

```
print "Value is: @{ [ $self->Test->{text} ] }\n";
```

Comment: A less-silly trick I would include in a list of such options: `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-function-calls-in-a-string%3F

For your example the best matching form would be in my opinion:

```
print "Value is: ${ \$self->Test->{text} } \n";
```

The question is the added value of the interpolation? It is supposed to be quicker then concatenation but based on http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/performance.html#Interpolation__Concatenation_or_List the difference is very small and the quickest way, in this particular print context, is:

```
print "Value is: ", $self->Test->{text}, " \n";
```